getTeamRepository() throws exception while running as a Java Plugin in Rhapsody but works well when ran from eclipse
I am working on a Rhapsody Java Plugin which connect with RTC to fetch some data. The code works fine in Eclipse when I run it as a Java Application. But when I load the same code as a plugin in Rhapsody, the getTeamRepository(repoURI) is throwing exceptions.
m_monitor = (IProgressMonitor) new NullProgressMonitor();

TeamPlatform.startup();

if(TeamPlatform.isStarted())
{
    try
    {
        m_iTeamRepository =  TeamPlatform.getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(repoUri);
        m_iTeamRepository.registerLoginHandler(new DefaultLoginHandler(l_userTID, l_userPassword));

        m_iTeamRepository.login(m_monitor);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        m_rhapsodyActiveApplication.writeToOutputWindow("Log", "\nException occurred while logging in User:"+l_userTID+"!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


Exception Log:
[2024-09-13 02:24:51 Proc=28524 Thr=15928 App=0xf8dde68] PLUGIN
MESSAGE: Exception while calling plugin method:
Plugin:exportFeatureLineUp.ExportFeatureLineUpPlugin
Method:RhpPluginInvokeItem
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)     at
com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.JavaPluginsManager.callPluginMethod(Unknown
Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:148)  at
java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:137)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepository.(TeamRepository.java:446)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepositoryService.createSharedTeamRepository(TeamRepositoryService.java:526)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepositoryService.getTeamRepository(TeamRepositoryService.java:113)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.TeamRepositoryService.getTeamRepository(TeamRepositoryService.java:132)
at exportFeatureLineUp.ExportFeatureLineUp.loginToRTC(XYZ.java:942)
at exportFeatureLineUp.ExportFeatureLineUp.runPlugin(XYZ.java:1031)
at
exportFeatureLineUp.ExportFeatureLineUpPlugin.RhpPluginInvokeItem(ExportFeatureLineUpPlugin.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type name Contributor and the namespace URI com.ibm.team.repository do not
resolve to an IItemType.
at
com.ibm.team.repository.common.internal.querypath.AbstractQueryPathModel$Implementation.getItemType(AbstractQueryPathModel.java:197)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.common.query.IQuery$Factory.newInstance(IQuery.java:129)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ContributorManager.createAllContributorsQuery(ContributorManager.java:72)
at
com.ibm.team.repository.client.internal.ContributorManager.(ContributorManager.java:60)


Is this the full log that you have given?

@AnishB. This is the part which gets printed after invoking the plugin in Rhapsody. The complete log will have everything right from when the plugins gets loaded. It gets loaded and I am able to invoke it as well. The exception occurs when it hits the getTeamRepository() function.

This errors happens because among the existing plugins in your rhapsody installation no one is identified with this values:

Contributor (of type IItemType)
namespace URI com.ibm.team.repository

Think of it as if Spring was not being able to resolve a bean with the type, the name and the "namespace" (which is a fancy name for an 'extension point' in Eclipse and Rhapsody argot).
I am not finding a lot of links on "how to show existing IItemTypes" through code, just this link with a video on how to create them visually, maybe it can guide you on what to do.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-can-i-add-custom-type-list-predefined-types-built-rhapsody
If I was you I would search in my IDE on how to grab all existing types passing the URI as a parameter or maybe the type (IItemType).
Sorry that I can't help any further, IBM does not easily provide this SW if you are not currently in a project with a paying customer :(.

It seems like the issue is due to missing dependencies when running your code as a Rhapsody plugin. In Eclipse, all the necessary libraries (like the RTC client libraries) are available in the classpath, so everything works fine. However, when you run it as a plugin in Rhapsody, those libraries might not be included by default.
The exception message:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type name Contributor and the namespace URI com.ibm.team.repository do not resolve to an IItemType.

suggests that the Contributor type from the com.ibm.team.repository namespace isn't being found. This usually happens when the required JAR files aren't available at runtime.
Here are a few things you can try:

Include RTC Client Libraries: Make sure that all the RTC client libraries your application depends on are included in the Rhapsody plugin's classpath. You might need to add the necessary JAR files to your plugin's build path or package them with the plugin.

Update Plugin Configuration: Check your plugin's manifest file (like plugin.xml or MANIFEST.MF) to ensure it's configured to import the required packages. Sometimes, plugins need explicit declarations to access certain classes.

Classloader Issues: Rhapsody might use a different classloader mechanism that doesn't automatically pick up all dependencies. You might need to adjust the classloader settings or use a custom classloader within your plugin.

Environment Differences: Verify if there are any differences between your Eclipse and Rhapsody environments, such as Java versions or other configurations that might affect class loading.

Logging: Add additional logging to see exactly where the failure occurs and which classes aren't being found. This might give you more clues about what's missing.


To include the RTC Client Libraries in your Rhapsody plugin, you'll need to make sure that all the necessary JAR files are accessible to your plugin at runtime. Here's a basic example of how you can do this:

Locate the RTC Client Libraries: Find the JAR files that contain the RTC client classes. These are usually located in the installation directory of your RTC Eclipse client or the Jazz Team Server. Common JAR files you might need include:

com.ibm.team.repository.client.jar
com.ibm.team.repository.common.jar
com.ibm.team.process.client.jar
Plus any other dependencies required by these JARs.


Add the JARs to Your Plugin Project:

Create a lib directory inside your plugin project.
Copy the necessary JAR files into this lib directory.


Update the Plugin Manifest (MANIFEST.MF):

Open your MANIFEST.MF file.

Add the JARs to the Bundle-ClassPath. It should look something like this:
Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/com.ibm.team.repository.client.jar, lib/com.ibm.team.repository.common.jar, lib/com.ibm.team.process.client.jar


Ensure that you separate each entry with a comma.



Import Necessary Packages:

Still in the MANIFEST.MF, import the required packages using Import-Package. For example:
Import-Package: com.ibm.team.repository.client,
com.ibm.team.repository.common,
com.ibm.team.process.client;resolution:=optional,
org.eclipse.core.runtime;resolution:=optional




Adjust Build Path:

Right-click on your project in Eclipse and go to Build Path > Configure Build Path.
Under the Libraries tab, add the JARs from your lib directory.


Rebuild and Test:

Rebuild your plugin project.
Deploy it to Rhapsody and test to see if the exception is resolved.



Example:
Here's how a section of your MANIFEST.MF might look:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: YourPluginName
Bundle-SymbolicName: your.plugin.id;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: your.plugin.Activator
Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/com.ibm.team.repository.client.jar, lib/com.ibm.team.repository.common.jar, lib/com.ibm.team.process.client.jar
Import-Package: com.ibm.team.repository.client,
 com.ibm.team.repository.common,
 com.ibm.team.process.client,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8

I hope this helps!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy: Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools may not be used to generate content for Stack Overflow. The content you provide must either be your own original work, or your summary of the properly referenced work of others.

We have beeen chatgpteized
